# How to convert mathematical expressions into C statement?

Tags: c, mathematical-expressions

How to convert each of the following mathematical expressions to its equivalent statement in C?

1. 1 / (x^2 + y^2)
2. square root of (b^2 - 4ac)

Comment: First you should try to learn the language you want to use. Then the answer will be trivial. some links that may help. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node17.html

Answer (score 6):

- `1.0 / (pow(x,2) + pow(y,2))`
- `sqrt(pow(b,2) - 4*a*c)`

See [`pow()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) and [`sqrt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt) functions manual.

You can also write `x*x` instead of `pow(x, 2)`. Both will have the exact same result and performance (the compiler knows what the `pow` function does and how to optimize it).

---

(For commenters)

GCC outputs the exact same assembler code for both of these functions:

```
double pow2_a(double x) {
    return pow(x, 2);
}

double pow2_b(double x) {
    return x * X;
}
```

Assembler:

```
    fldl    4(%esp)
    fmul    %st(0), %st
    ret
```

Comment: using pow is unnecessary here

Comment: what's the benefit of not using it ? (given that it's a compiler intrinsic in most compilers)

Comment: Are you suggesting that `pow(x, 2.0)` will be optimized to `x*x`?

Comment: Really does the compiler (let's say GCC and VC++) know how to optimize  `pow(x, 2.0)` (because in C there is only the `double, double` "variant")?

Comment: It's a more accurate translation of the source code (and better for teaching imo). Besides using `x * x` is a premature optimization (GCC 4.5.2 compiles `pow(x,2)` to `x*x` even without optimization enabled)

Comment: Well, but x*x is less to type.

Comment: With a single-letter variable, yes